# Get new created entry IDs in loop

Tags: symfony, doctrine

In my Symfony 3 application, I need to get IDs of new created entries.

My code is:

```
foreach(array('a', 'b', 'c') as $value){
    $entry = new Entry();
    $entry->seName($value);
    $em->persist($entry);
}
$em->flush();
```

I use $em->flush(); only once, and could not use it on every iteration because this block is on a transaction.

Is it possible to get IDs of new created entries in this case?

Comment: Not really.  The id's are generated by the database.  The database only comes into play when you flush.  You can use a [Identifier Generation Strategy](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/basic-mapping.html#identifier-generation-strategies) of 'none' and then generate your own id's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The autoincremented IDs are not created before you do a flush so you cannot access the ids before.

It is hard to say what exactly your use case here is, but you can ofc store the created entities in array and access the ids from there after the flush if that would solve your issue:

```
$entries = [];

foreach(array('a', 'b', 'c') as $value){
    $entry = new Entry();
    $entry->seName($value);
    $entries[] = $entry;
    $em->persist($entry);
}
$em->flush();

foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    var_dump($entry->getId());
}
```